# Redirect URL from Virtual root subdomain to addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hello there I have a fossis.org as my virtualroot so my addon domains are created inside the public_html directory.i have addon domain called www.techiestuffs.com which is in public_html/techiestufs directory.

Now my problem is it became two different version of the same site.You can see that by visitng www.techiestuffs.com and  http://fossis.org/techiestuffs .So my entire site is became as duplicate contents and many URL from http://fossis.org/techiestuffs also indexed in search engine.
Both the website uses Drupal7 CMS.

Does anyone know how to redirect the later one to earlier one that is fossis.org/techiestuffs to techiestuffs.com .

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this, for `public_html/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fossis.org$
RewriteRule techiestuffs(/.*)? http://www.techiestuffs.com$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: it doesnt work.I think something should be added in .htaccess at public_html/techiestuffs as well.Because you can see that fossis.org doesnt take www. but for this techiestuffs directory it takes www because techiestuffs.com uses www.

Comment: @vividvilla - Doesn't matter.  I even tested this locally.  Basically, as you asked, this will redirect any requests to the `techiestuffs` directory to the same path on the `www.techiestuffs.com` domain - but only if the original request came in on `fossis.org` - so this will only match requests of `http://fossis.org/techiestuffs/*`.  As long as this URL is working, you should be set.

Comment: But the URL http://fossis.org/techiestuffs/ is not redirected to www.techiestuffs.com

Comment: @vividvilla - this is exactly what the rules I provided should accomplish.  You don't have any related rules above this (including anything with `[L]`) that would prevent this rules from being effective, do you?  Please post your entire Apache configuration (any `*.conf` files and your entire `.htaccess` file) if you need additional assistance.

Comment: since i use shared hosting i cant get access to .conf file but here is .htaccess file - http://pastebin.com/N7wRkM6f

Comment: Without being able to directly experiment with this, my guess would be that lines 87-88 are preventing your redirect from completing as expected (contains the `[L]`, which will prevent further rewrite actions).  You also don't need to repeat lines 145-146 (the `Options` and `RewriteEngine On`, as they are already present above in the file.  Finally, this file is processed in-order, so you may need to include the remaining lines that I provided elsewhere within the file (in relation to the other directives) to have the intended effect.

Comment: Finally, try to simplify this to a smaller, simpler example (backup the existing configuration first), get this portion working by itself, then start adding back in the existing configurations - testing everything as you go.